# Adding Handler with Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

I use following code to register httpHandler during initial application setup.

```
class SomeHandler: IHttpAsyncHandler {

    public void Register() {
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) {

            string SITE_NAME = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
            string APP_PATH = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetVirtualPath();
            string SERVICE_CLASS = GetType().FullName.ToString();
            string HANDLER_NAME = GetType().Name;

            ConfigurationElementCollection CEC = serverManager
                .GetWebConfiguration(SITE_NAME, APP_PATH)
                .GetSection("system.webServer/handlers")
                .GetCollection();

            ConfigurationElement ele = null;
            foreach (ConfigurationElement ele1 in CEC) {
                if (ele1.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString() == HANDLER_NAME) {
                    ele = ele1;
                }
            }
            if (ele == null) {
                ele = CEC.CreateElement("add");
                ele["name"] = HANDLER_NAME;
                ...
                CEC.Add(ele);
                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

**Problem**

It adds the handler correctly and handler works fine too. However there is an issue.
Initially my web.config looks like this

```xml
<configuration>
    <appSettings />
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
        </handlers>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
    ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The desired effect of code above should be as following

```xml
<configuration>
    <appSettings />
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="SomeHandler" path="..." verb="..." type="NameSpace.SomeHandler" />
        </handlers>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
    ...
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But instead I get following

[image: issue with adding handler]

**Note** that handlers are cleared and all the inherited handlers from IIS server (72 of them) added then my handler is added at the end.

**Question**

Is it possible to somehow stop `CommitChanges()` method from adding clear and then all the handlers to local `web.config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I needed a little more search.

CarlosAg in [this comment](https://forums.iis.net/p/1159341/1910692.aspx#1910692) says

> Since this collection is a "mergeAppend='false'" collection it has
> that behavior of adding elements at the bottom and having to bring all
> of the parent ones to ensure semantics are correct.
>
> To have the semantic of adding yours at the top (and prevent the
> parent ones to be copied) just change the line:
>
> handlersCollection.Add(addElement);
>
> to be:
>
> handlersCollection.AddAt(0, addElement);

Thus changing `CEC.Add(ele)` to `CEC.AddAt(0, ele)` fixed the problem